# Converting multiview drawing to isometric drawing

Tags: technical-drawing, drafting, architecture

[image]

Please help me answer this. There is more to this but I just need to know the trick so I can answer the rest please.

Comment: Welcome to engineeering stackexchange. Can you tell what your done? Then we will help correct you. **Note** we don't answer home problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn to think in 3D.

Print out your drawing and fold the views into their correct relative locations.

[image]

*Figure 1. The plan, elevation and end view projected onto a cube.*

Draw that in isometric view and start cutting out (erasing lines and drawing new ones) the various sections indicated by the solid lines.

Post your efforts in the question.

When you are finished you could mock it up in 3D CAD (http://onshape.com is free if you make your designs public) and then create a 2D drawing and see if the plan and elevations match.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of question I usually start with a solid cube the limits of object.  I then start making shapes of the material that needs to be removed and subtracting it from the solid object.  Those negative shapes I base of the 2d face views.

When it comes to something more plate like with lots of curves to it, I will go the route of drawing the outline in 2D, extruding the 2D shape to make a solid.  I will then add/or subtract other shapes as needed.